# Converting datetime to POSIX time

Tags: python, datetime, posix

How do I convert a datetime or date object into a POSIX timestamp in python?  There are methods to create a datetime object out of a timestamp, but I don't seem to find any obvious ways to do the operation the opposite way.

Comment: The answers to this question are no longer up to date. You should use the `.timestamp()` method of `datetime.datetime` objects as pointed out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007272/8784382). Please mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Also make sure that when you call `.timestamp()` you are using a timezone aware date object as timezone naive  "[are assumed to represent local time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
import time, datetime

d = datetime.datetime.now()
print time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it had to be something stupidly simple, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It seems that depending on the platform, time doesn't have a mktime method

Comment: Note this gives local time, not UTC. For UTC see [fixermark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5872022/60075).

Comment: To be precise: Note that `mktime` *expects as input* local time, and the output has no timezone — its a Unix timestamp, which are durations measured in seconds (and always from the epoch, thus giving you a time). (`datetime.now()` returns the current local time.)

Comment: there is 50% chance it returns wrong result during DST transition. See [Problems with Localtime](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime).

Comment: Note that since posix timestamps are only precise to the second, the datetime is truncated to the second by the `timetuple()` step.  So by necessity precision is lost by doing this conversion.

Comment: It's incorrect. `time.mktime(datetime(2016,2,4,tzinfo=timezone.utc).utctimetuple())` gives `1454533200`, but should give `1454544000`

Answer (score 23):

For UTC calculations, `calendar.timegm` is the inverse of `time.gmtime`.

```
import calendar, datetime
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
```

Comment: Note: `calendar.timegm()` expects UTC input but the result (timestamp) is not in any timezone. It is just seconds elapsed since the epoch  (== 1969-12-31T19:00:00-05:00 (New York) == 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (UTC) == 1970-01-01T03:00:00+03:00 (Moscow)) -- a single fixed moment in time.

Comment: Correction: due to intercalary leap seconds, "seconds since Epoch" are not *elapsed* SI seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00`. [`utc_to_tai()` function](https://gist.github.com/zed/a912498be36c6a947c33#file-utc_to_tai-py-L25) could be used to compute the elapsed SI seconds.

Answer (score 15):

Note that Python now (3.5.2) includes a [built-in method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) for this in `datetime` objects:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 18, 52, 47, 874766)
>>> now.timestamp() # Local time
1605743567.874766
>>> now.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp() # UTC
1605725567.874766 # 5 hours delta (I'm in UTC-5)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? `now` is a timezone naive datetime object and calling `.timestamp` on it is first going to assume that the object is in local time (which it is -- implicitly and luckily) and then do the conversion to provide a posix compliant timestamp (seconds since UTC Unix time).

Comment: @Marc I don't understand your comment: I explicitly say `# Local time` in the example next to the call to `now.timestamp()`.  Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: `now.timestamp()` gives you is a posix compliant timestamp, and it is a correct utc Unix epoch timestamp here since `now` at this point is a naive timestamp with your local timezone implicitly used.  When calling `.timestamp` on a naive datetime object [it will assume a local timezone](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) (which it is) and give you a correct UTC unix timestamp.

When you call `replace` however, there are no conversions done to the datetime object, it will just convert `now` from naive -> aware. And this seems wrong in most cases.

Comment: Oh, the `now` part is irrelevant in this answer.  Feel free to edit it to show a date literal instead.

Comment: `now` is only relevant because of how it affects `now.timestamp()`'s output. To take `now` out of this conversation we can do `datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()` this is just as good as `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()`.  They both have the same problem, `.timestamp()` will most likely assume the wrong timezone. Time is confusing, so I could be wrong, but that is how I understand the documentation.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you can just remove the call to `now()` in my answer if you prefer it that way, which I just did.

Comment: The changes made did not fix the problem. It's still dealing with a timezone naive datetime object.  Your previous solution was actually closer to the truth than this current iteration.

Comment: All this answer does is point you to the existence of `.timestamp()`; if you have a naive timestamp Python makes an assumption about what your datetime means; otherwise, it doesn't have to guess.  If you want to make sure that it doesn't guess, you can set the tzinfo of your datetime.

Answer (score 4):

In python, time.time() can return seconds as a floating point number that includes a decimal component with the microseconds. In order to convert a datetime back to this representation, you have to add the microseconds component because the direct timetuple doesn't include it.

```
import time, datetime

posix_now = time.time()

d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(posix_now)
no_microseconds_time = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
has_microseconds_time = time.mktime(d.timetuple()) + d.microsecond * 0.000001

print posix_now
print no_microseconds_time
print has_microseconds_time
```

Comment: don't use local time for a round-trip (ts -> local -> ts). It might break during DST transitions. You could easily extend [timegm()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/calendar.py#l597) to include microseconds and use it for ts -> utc -> ts transformations.

Answer (score 2):

## It depends

Is your datetime object timezone aware or naive?

## Timezone Aware

If it is aware it's simple ([and recommended](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now))

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
aware_date = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
posix_timestamp = aware_date.timestamp()
```

as [date.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) gives you "POSIX timestamp"

***NOTE**: more accurate to call it an epoch/unix timestamp as [it may not be POSIX compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Non-synchronous_Network_Time_Protocol-based_variant)*

## Timezone Naive

If it's not timezone aware (naive), then you'd need to know what timezone it was originally in so we can use [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to convert it into a timezone aware date object. Let's assume that you've stored/retrieved it as UTC Naive. Here we create one, as an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
naive_date = datetime.utcnow()  # this date is naive, but is UTC based
aware_date = naive_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)  # this date is no longer naive

# now we do as we did with the last one

posix_timestamp = aware_date.timestamp()
```

It's always better to get to a timezone aware date as soon as you can to prevent issues that can arise with naive dates (as Python will often assume they are local times and can mess you up)

***NOTE**: also be careful with your understanding of the epoch as it is platform dependent*

Answer (score 0):

Best conversion from posix/epoch to datetime timestamp and the reverse:

```
this_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # datetime.datetime type
epoch_time = this_time.timestamp()      # posix time or epoch time
this_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
```

Comment: `utcnow` outputs a timezone naive datetime object and when running `.timestamp()` on it, python will assume a local timezone (even though it's UTC naive, not Local Naive) and this should give you incorrect feedback.