# Convert python aware datetime to local timetuple

Tags: python, datetime, epoch, python-datetime

I have an aware `datetime` object:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'))
```

I'm using this to convert the object to timestamp and it currently runs fine:

```
int(time.mktime(dt.utctimetuple()))
```

But according to [time docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), `time.mktime` requires local `timetuple`, not UTC `timetuple`. How do I get local `timetuple` from an aware `datetime`? Or is any other way to make `timestamp` instead of `time.mktime`?

I have read this question and it seems that I should use `calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())`.
[Converting datetime to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554365/converting-datetime-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here?  You have an aware `datetime`, and you what to get what?

Comment: I want to get the Unix timestamp corresponding to `datetime`.

Comment: So `time.mktime` is wrong.

Comment: BTW you should add your comment in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an aware datetime you can convert it to a unix epoch timestamp by subtracting a datetime at UTC epoch like:

#### Code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

def aware_to_epoch(aware):
    # get a datetime that is equal to epoch in UTC
    utc_at_epoch = pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1))

    # return the number of seconds since epoch
    return (aware - utc_at_epoch).total_seconds()

aware = dt.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'))
print(aware_to_epoch(aware))
```

#### Results:

```
1521612302.341014
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your are confused on what do you want.

Based on your comment, the answer is in python `datetime` documentation:

> There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive datetime instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying tzinfo=timezone.utc:
>
> ```
> timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
> ```
>
> or by calculating the timestamp directly:
>
> timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)

Comment: `dt` is timezone aware and it's in UTC+7. `int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))` returns wrong result.