# How to convert date and time string to POSIX time?

Tags: python, datetime, posix

I have two string :

```
date = '2017-05-09'
time = '19:28'
```

How do I convert this to posix time ?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/2803852/3521116 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/255035/3521116

Comment: Keep in mind that `mktime()` expects local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process as follow:

Convert the string date and time to `datetime.datetime` instance.
Convert this instance to posix time:

```
import datetime
import time

my_date = '2017-05-09'
my_time = '19:28'

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date + " " + my_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
posix_dt = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the `datetime` library. Also, *keep in mind that the two methods presented below* ***expect local time***.

With

```
>>> date = '2017-05-09'
>>> time_ = '19:28'
```

---

For 2.7.+ versions (may be lower versions also) of python, you first have to turn your string into a datetime object

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> date_object = dt.datetime.strptime('{d} {t}'.format(d=date, t=time_), 
                                       "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 9, 19, 28)
```

Note that I changed your variable `time` into `time_`, so as not to create conflicts of name afterward. Getting a posix time is easy to do with `date_object`

```
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime(date_object.timetuple())
1494350880.0 #Given my local time !
```

---

For 3.+ versions of python, it is even more direct than above

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime.strptime('{d} {t}'.format(d=date, t=time_), 
                         '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').timestamp()
1494350880.0 #Given my local time !
```